# Regex won't find the designated string

Tags: php, regex

I lately got back in to regex and I'm working on a simple log highlighting system. Currently I have a specific problem with one expression.

For example, this is what appears in the log file:

```
15:49:19 - <img=ico_headshot> player1
00:00:53 - <img=ico_headshot> player2
```

This is what my regex string looks like:

```
/[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\s\-\s<img=ico_headshot>\s(.*)/
```

I tried this in numerous regEx online testers and they show that the regex string and the string from the logs do match.

This is how it works in the file: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5960ccbcf21832d727c1a097c0878cb1

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have not posted the code that fails. The [regex works](https://regex101.com/r/wB3uD4/1) with the strings you posted. That means there might be an issue with whitespaces, try `\s*` instead of `\s` everywhere, but we cannot help since we cannot repro.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this regular expression.

By using Java:

```
"^[0-9:]+\\s-\\s(.*)\\s(.*)$"
```

By using PHP:

```
'/^[0-9:]+\s-\s(.*)\s(.*)$/'
```